# What is the term for a specific type of collocation analysis

Tags: terminology, computational-linguistics, collocations

I am trying to write a text processing script in R. I am interested in finding a word (from a list of words I have selected) only if it is in the same sentence as another word. 
Eventually I would also like to do this for the co-existence of words in the same paragraph and other text lengths.
I am aware of collocation analysis but this usually relies on words that are actually next to each other. What is the analysis called that I want to perform?